# Remove duplicate values from a dictionary based on a condition

Tags: c#, dictionary, duplicates, filtering

I have a dictionary returned from a query which can have duplicate values for different keys. In this case , the priority is **the one with Account!= null**(in the following sample , the first one)

how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you've done to solve this so far?

Comment: @RandRandom ... not fishy... duplicates in values

Comment: Account is not a "value" but a property of the key object

Comment: @GianlucaConte I didnt mean Account, KEY is set of objects, one of them is Account. if you check the values , you can see the duplicate. I already highlighted them

Comment: A lot is missing here. How is the dictionary defined? defintions of all types. Pleas provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Key must be a defined type, not a "set of object". Acconunt is just a property of the object KeyObject, assuming that z is of type Dictionary<KeyObject,ValueObject>

Comment: The best that I can suggest you is  z.Where(s => s.Key.Account != null); considering the fragmentary informations

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Distinct` function.

Like this

> var distinct = mydict.Values.Distinct()

Comment: it doest work this way, the Values are not the same.duplication is part of the value , so it cant be removed in distinct . Also , I have a priority in removing them , it cant be just remove the first /or second....

Comment: Please provide a minimal example showing what you are trying to do, what you did, describe what the code does, and explain why that's wrong and what the expected behaviour is.